# Issues when try to apply css class on rows

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I've got this table:

```
<table id="mytable" st-safe-src="dataSetREST" st-table="displayed" class="table table-responsive portlet-body panel-body">
                    <thead>
                        <tr >
                            <th >A</th>
                            <th >B</th>
                            <th >C</th>
                            <th >D</th>
                            <th >E</th>
                            <th >F</th>
                            <th >G</th>
                            <th >H</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody data-ng-dblclick="scrollTo()">

                        <tr data-ng-repeat="row in displayed" st-select-row="row" st-select-mode="single" data-ng-class="{'selected':$index == selectedRow}" data-ng-click="setClickedRow($index)">
                            <td data-ng-click="$parent.selData(row);">{{$index}}</td>
                            <td data-ng-click="$parent.selData(row);">{{row.asd}}</td>
                            <td data-ng-click="$parent.selData(row);">{{row.sad}}</td>
                            <td data-ng-click="$parent.selData(row);">{{row.dsa}}</td>
                            <td data-ng-click="$parent.selData(row);">{{row.das}}</td>
                            <td data-ng-click="$parent.selData(row);">{{row.sda}}</td>
                            <td data-ng-click="$parent.selData(row);">{{row.ads}}</td>
                            <td data-ng-click="$parent.selData(row);">{{row.etc}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

I need to apply a background color on the selected row. In the controller I added this:

```
$scope.selectedRow = null;
$scope.setClickedRow = function(index){
     $scope.selectedRow = index;
}
```

It should work since in data-ng-click I send the index to the method, but it didn't enter the method (or at least didnt print a console.log() placed inside). Here the css class:

```
.selected {
    background-color: #67BBED;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this fiddle it's working great http://jsfiddle.net/linkolen/tq31h4bw/#base

```js
angular.module('myApp', []);

function TestCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.selectedRow = null;
    $scope.displayed = [{asd:3},{asd:3},{asd:3},{asd:3},{asd:3},{asd:3}]
$scope.setClickedRow = function(index){
     $scope.selectedRow = index;
}
}
```

```css
.selected {
    background-color: #67BBED;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="TestCtrl">
<table id="mytable" st-safe-src="dataSetREST" st-table="displayed" class="table table-responsive portlet-body panel-body">
                    <thead>
                        <tr >
                            <th >A</th>
                            <th >B</th>
                            <th >C</th>
                            <th >D</th>
                            <th >E</th>
                            <th >F</th>
                            <th >G</th>
                            <th >H</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody data-ng-dblclick="scrollTo()">

                        <tr data-ng-repeat="row in displayed" st-select-row="row" st-select-mode="single" data-ng-class="{'selected':$index == selectedRow}" data-ng-click="setClickedRow($index)">
                            <td data-ng-click="$parent.selData(row);">{{$index}}</td>
                            <td data-ng-click="$parent.selData(row);">{{row.asd}}</td>
                            <td data-ng-click="$parent.selData(row);">{{row.sad}}</td>
                            <td data-ng-click="$parent.selData(row);">{{row.dsa}}</td>
                            <td data-ng-click="$parent.selData(row);">{{row.das}}</td>
                            <td data-ng-click="$parent.selData(row);">{{row.sda}}</td>
                            <td data-ng-click="$parent.selData(row);">{{row.ads}}</td>
                            <td data-ng-click="$parent.selData(row);">{{row.etc}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
 <div>
```

Comment: This is weird, but in my project it just don't enter the method.

Comment: if you noticed i do not have this in my fiddle data-ng-click="$parent.selData(row);" the ng-click on table td elements may be it's what causing you problems

Comment: I tryed to remove the ng-clicks and ng-dbl-clicks but keep not working, and console didnt print the console.log on the method, I know this is pretty weird but Ireally need this working, have any idea what is avoiding my application to enter the method?

Comment: could you create a fiddle or plnkr of your code so i can help you

Comment: Since it's a enterprise code, I think i can't provide, but if you want something specific, just ask

Comment: check my provided fiddle what are the differences between my code and yours? why mine is working and yours not

Comment: Well i have more content in my controller, but it's just it doesn't access the method. I'l keep checking for differences.

Comment: well try this change your data-ng-click="setClickedRow($index)" TO data-ng-click="$parent.setClickedRow($index)" and data-ng-class="{'selected':$index == $parent.selectedRow}"

Comment: If you're still there, know any way to clear selection when I use pagination? I'm having troubles to achieve and don't feel in the mod to post another question.

Comment: try to do this on page change $scope.selectedRow = null;

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ternary operator` in expressions. Just give a try

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="row in displayed" st-select-row="row" st-select-mode="single" data-ng-click="selectedRow = $index" data-ng-class="$index == selectedRow ? 'selected' : ' '" >
```

I think your `ng-click` works later and you're applying class first.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't completely work, since it keep selected all rows i click on.

Comment: I just didnt explain well myself on previus comment, as u suggest it changes the color, but when i select other row both keep the background color. No console errors.

Comment: Worked the same way the previous on my application